# Stored procedure not returning value when executed from code, works fine from management studio

Tags: c#, sql-server, xml

I have a proc like

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[ExportTestAsXML]
    @TestId         int
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    declare @x xml;
    set @x = (
       select
          (select * from table1 where testid = @TestId FOR XML auto, Type, Elements),
          (select * from table2 where testid = @TestId FOR XML auto, Type, Elements),
          (select * from table3 
           where objectiveid in 
               (select objectiveid from objectives where testid = @TestId) 
           FOR XML auto, Type, Elements),
          (select * from table4 
           where objectiveid in 
               (select objectiveid from objectives where testid = @TestId) 
           FOR XML auto, Type, Elements),
          (select * from table5 
           where questionid in 
               (select questionid from questions 
                where objectiveid in 
                      (select objectiveid from objectives where testid = @TestId)
               ) 
           FOR XML auto, Type, Elements)
       for xml path(''), type
    );

   select @x as my_xml
END
```

When I run it from SQL Server 2005 Management Studio I get a table with a single record containing the combined XML from the select statements. When I run it from my web service code and use the datatable visualizer to check the table it is empty.  Here is the code I use to execute the proc

```
SqlParameter[] Parameters = new SqlParameter[1];
Parameters[0] = new SqlParameter();
Parameters[0].ParameterName = "@TestId";
Parameters[0].Value = TestId;
Parameters[0].SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Int;
Parameters[0].Size = 50;

DataTable data = ExecuteDataSet("ExportTestAsXML", Parameters);

private DataTable ExecuteDataSet(string storedProcName, SqlParameter[] parameters)
{
    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand();
    command.CommandText = storedProcName;
    command.Parameters.AddRange(parameters);
    command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    command.Connection = (SqlConnection)dcMUPView.Connection;

    command.Connection.Open();
    command.Prepare();

    SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
    DataTable ds = new DataTable();
    adapter.Fill(ds);

    command.Connection.Close();
    return ds;
}
```

Any idea what is going on?

Comment: @Siva may be right: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter.parametername.aspx

Comment: Yeah that makes sense but after fixing it I'm still getting the same result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your sample works if you populate a `DataSet` instead of a `DataTable`.

Here is a copy of your source with the minimum changes required. Note that when you're using a `DataSet` you should add code to check whether any tables were returned, and whether there are rows in the first table available, etc.

Caller:

```
SqlParameter[] Parameters = new SqlParameter[1];
Parameters[0] = new SqlParameter();
Parameters[0].ParameterName = "@TestId";
Parameters[0].Value = TestId;
Parameters[0].SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Int;
Parameters[0].Size = 50;

DataSet data = ExecuteDataSet("ExportTestAsXML", Parameters);

// Read First table (Tables[0]), First Row (Rows[0]), First Column of that Row (Rows[0][0])
System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write(data.Tables[0].Rows[0][0]);
```

Method:

```
private DataSet ExecuteDataSet(string storedProcName, SqlParameter[] parameters)
{
    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand();
    command.CommandText = storedProcName;
    command.Parameters.AddRange(parameters);
    command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    command.Connection = (SqlConnection)dcMUPView.Connection;

    command.Connection.Open();
    command.Prepare();

    SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet ();
    adapter.Fill(ds);

    command.Connection.Close();
    return ds;
}
```